# Checking proof that $\sum(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to show (or disprove) that the series $\sum(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ converges. I tried using the root test, namely, showing that the $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}(|(-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt n}|)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{\sqrt n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{2n}}})<1$$ This seems clear, as for all $n>1$, $n^{\frac{1}{2n}}>1$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Why do you think it is correct?

Comment: Exercise: $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}=1}$.

Comment: @Bumblebee My mistake.  I knew it was convergent, but I didn't fully appreciate that limsup=1, not < 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't correct. The limsup is equal to $1$ here, not less than $1$. Anyway, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a well known divergent series, so there is no way the root test would be able to help you prove convergence here. The series is not absolutely convergent.

The convergence of the original series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ follows directly from Leibniz test.